# JPopupMenu in Java3d applet does not receive mouse or keyboard input

Tags: java, swing, java-3d, jpopupmenu

I have a a Java application that uses Java3D and JPopupMenus filled with JMenuItems. Everything works fine when it runs as a regular application-- the JPopupMenus and everything else behave as expected.  However, when I make an applet out of the application, the JPopupMenu that pops up entirely over the Canvas3D does not act as expected. The JPopupMenu behaves as follows:

1. The menu items do not highlight as the mouse moves over them
2. The arrow keys cannot be used to move through the menu items
3. Clicking on a top-level JMenuItem completes the action and highlights the item, but it does not dispose of the JPopupMenu as it does in the regular application
4. Clicking on a top-level JMenuItem that contatins a submenu does nothing
5. Clicking outside of the JPopupMenu does not dispose of the JPopupMenu as it does in the regular application
6. With the JPopupMenu displayed, opening a JPopupMenu on top of the swing portion of my program enables regular and expected behavior of the JPopupMenu over the Canvas3D, but point 5 still applies

Some more information:

- The JPopupMenu is displayed with JPopupMenu.show() in relation to the JPanel holding the Canvas3D
- I am calling JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) before the creation of any JPopupMenus, but this line doesn't seem to make a difference.
- I thought that this might have been a focus issue, but JPopupMenu.requestFocusInWindow() doesn't work

So my question is: what is causing the behavior to be different between the application and the applet, and how can I make the JPopupMenu in the applet function as it does in the application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change lightweight JPopup to heavyweight hard to talk something else without posting your SSCCE

Comment: JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) is supposed to make all JPopupMenus created after that call heavyweight.  Also, I'll work on an SSCCE, but there's a lot of code required to get a basic implementation going, and I feel that this is probably more of a concept question, since the desktop application works fine, and only the applet breaks down.

Comment: @maher.cs AFAIK all good workarounds for CAD/CAM, 3D etc. are bases on AWT, maybe you have to use AWT Popup with Swing JMenuItem  or e.i., mixing heavyweight container with lightweight JComponents, are you able to test that with GlassPane (set for BorderLayout and put there nonopaque JLabel with some Background and Aplpha transparency), if will be GlassPane behind, then you have to use AWT popup Containers without exceptions

Comment: I'm working on testing this now, but wouldn't the JPopupMenu not appear at all if it were lightweight?  Canvas3D is heavyweight, so I would expect to not see the JPopupMenu at all, according to http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/.

Comment: Switching everything to AWT did the trick.  Thanks for suggesting that path.

Comment: glad to help you, eeeehmmm true is ... I bothering with that more than one week

Answer (score 0):

I solved by setting the invoker on the JPopMenu and make it HeavyWeight

```
final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
popup.setInvoker(myJFrame);
```